Moderators, can you please unfreeze this chat room?
I have delayed on keeping it alive due to some unexpected circumstances. However, I am still eager to continue that fellowship. So, please, unfeeze it:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153798/discussion-on-answer-by-js-witness-how-do-we-know-from-the-bible-that-adam-and-e

Sure, you - or anyone can just @ me on this comment thread if you need another room unfrozen.

@PeterTurner - Thank you so much!!!
